# I want to center a <ul> button but just can't do it

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a button and I just can't center it on the page. Here is the CSS.

```
.banners {padding:12px 0 0 0}
.banners li {float:left;font-size:26px;line-height:2.4em;letter-spacing:-1px;margin-left:6px}
.banners li:first-child {margin-left:0}
.banners li a {width:242px;display:block;height:65px;background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/banner-bg.gif) no-repeat left top;text-align:center;color:#fff;text-decoration:none}
```

Here is the html

```
<ul class="banners wrapper">
    <li><a href="#">UNLIMITED<b> $49</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that I need to put it in a <div>?

Comment: What is your rule for `wrapper`? Also, you have `float:left;` applied to the `li`, seems to me that would disrupt your centering efforts.

Comment: .wrapper {width:100%;overflow:hidden}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will center only the link**

The html:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#">UNLIMITED<b> $49</b></a>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.buttons {
  text-align:center
}
```

**This will center the link with a background image**

The html:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#">UNLIMITED<b> $49</b></a>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.buttons {
  text-align:center
}
.buttons a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 242px;
  height: 65px;
  background-image:url("bg.jpg");
  line-height:60px; /* <-- If you want the text centered, play with this value */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd be grateful if you could take a look. It's http://camuk-hosting.com/hosting.html - I basically want to get the button that says 'unlimited' to center on the page! I put it in a table, but I'm sure that's not the best way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the ways browsers handle margin and padding with ul,li are different. First, we need to neutralize it by applying `margin-left:0`to li and `padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;`to create a consistent behavior across browsers. And apply display:block to your a tag.

Just some simple styles, you should get what you want

```
.banners
{
   padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
   list-style-type:none;
}

.banners li{
   margin-left:0px;
}

.banners li a{
    display:block;
    height:65px;
    background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/banner-bg.gif)

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

`margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` to center block elements. And you should control your space using padding of `.banners li a`.